# Редактирование документа OpenXML docx

Tags: ms-word, .net

Извлекаю из zip-архива файл document.xml, пишу в него код вида
    <w:r>      
        <w:t>текст</w:t>
     </w:r>
после блока <w:body>, сохраняю, меняю расширение на docx обратно. Пытаюсь открыть в MSWord - пишет, что файл поврежден. Изначально документ открывался. В чём может быть ошибка ?

Comment: Очевидно, ваши изменения не соответствуют формату OOXML. _Ваш К.О._

Comment: Вы про этот ? http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший пример http://habrahabr.ru/post/109820/

Comment: О, вот видите! И велосипед оказался не нужен.